# Special linear group matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to figure out how the group $SL(2,3)$ works but I don't really understand it.

Say I have the matrix $B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ then how should I calculate $B^2$. (apparently B has order 2)

Comment: What is $SL(2,3)$?

Comment: Special linear group of degree 2 over a finite field of order 3.

Comment: Do you know ordinary matrix multiplication $\times$? it seems to be that $B^2 = B \times B$, and it calculates to the identity matrix.

Comment: I've seen that $B^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 &0 \\ 0 &2 \end{pmatrix}$ but I don't see why this is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that with SL$(2,3)$ you mean SL$_2(\Bbb F_3)$, that is all $2\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in the finite field $\Bbb F_3$. I remind you that in this field $2=-1$.

In such case, yourmatrix $B$ has order $4$. Indeed, as you have already commented above,

$$B^2=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Similarly

$$B^3=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2\\
2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2\\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally $$B^4=(B^2)^2=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, the matrix $B$ has order $2$ if you consider PSL$_2(\Bbb F_3)$, defined as

$$ \text{SL}_2(\Bbb F_3)/\{\pm Id\}$$